# How to add text in a bootstrap card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create something like below -

[image]

The card is indicated by the blue color inside which we have two texts. My approach was to add two divs inside the card div but the problem I am facing with that is, I want to put an image in the card and adding it in background doesn't fill the whole card and leaves some margin, which I tried to fix but didn't work.And have to write a lot of css to fix the margins padding etc for both image and text.

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

In place of blue color I will have an image.

Comment: You want like that? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#image-overlays

Comment: what are you trying to do?